# Help with RSA cryptography

Tags: cryptography

I need to find *c* of the encryption of *m = 100* using RSA given " *p = 89, q = 101 and e = 7* ". Then, i need to decypher the obtained *c*

I have already calculated *n = p * q*, which is 8,989 and *φ(n) = (p-1)(q-1)* which is 8,800

For calculating *d* i found the formula *de ≡ 1 (mod φ(n))* quite confusing, so i used *d = 1 + (k) * φ(n) / e* (which, as far as I'm concerned works the same), by doing that I got 1,257.

I'm not sure if there's a way to calculate *c ≡ m^e (mod n)* much more efficiently, because i just did the *100^7* operation, which is quite large, and calculating the *mod* i got *7170*, resulting *c = 7170*.

How do I decypher *c* efficiently? Using the RSA formula for decyphering *(M = C^d mod pq)* the operation would be structured like this: *M = 7170^1257 mod 8,989*, and it's to big of a number to calculate.

Comment: Your $de$ is equal to $-1$ mod $8800$, not $+1$. (A simple check would have told you this!) So you need $d=-1257\bmod 8800=7543$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @TonyK, first convert the exponent 7543 to binary:

$$7543 = (1110101110111)_2 = 2^{12}+2^{11}+2^{10}+2^8+2^6+2^5+2^4+2^2+2^1+2^0$$

Then calculate the power (modulus 8800) in ladder powers of 2:

$$7180^{(2^1)} = 7180^2 = 2000$$
$$7180^{(2^2)} = 2000^2 = 4800$$
$$7180^{(2^3)} = 4800^2 = 1600$$
$$7180^{(2^4)} = 1600^2 = 8000$$
$$7180^{(2^5)} = 8000^2 = 6400$$
$$7180^{(2^6)} = 6400^2 = 4800(!)$$
$$7180^{(2^7)} = 4800^2 = 1600$$
$$7180^{(2^8)} = 1600^2 = 8000$$
$$7180^{(2^9)} = 8000^2 = 6400$$
$$7180^{(2^{10})} = 6400^2 = 4800$$
$$7180^{(2^{11})} = 4800^2 = 1600$$
$$7180^{(2^{12})} = 1600^2 = 8000$$

Finally,

$$7180^{7543} = 7180^{(2^{12}+2^{11}+2^{10}+2^8+2^6+2^5+2^4+2^2+2^1+2^0)}$$
$$=8000\times1600\times4800\times8000\times4800\times6400\times8000\times4800\times2000\times7180$$

which we (ie. computers) can do as quickly as $1+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating $7180^{7543}$ and then reducing mod $8800$ would be ridiculously inefficient.

A simple method, which is very fast for numbers this small, is to reduce mod $8800$ after every multiplication. That way, you never have to deal with numbers greater than $8799\times 7543$.

But for cryptographically strong numbers, hundreds of digits long, you need to use a powering ladder. See [this link](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/12/10/fast-exponentiation/) for a description.